# Subset a np.matrix efficiently based on boolean np.array but only until certain treshold

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So lets say we have a Matrix M

```
M=np.array([[1,2,3],
            [1,2,3],
            [1,2,3],
            [1,2,3]
            [1,2,3],
            [1,2,3]])
```

with the same number of rows as the length of a np.array mask:

```
mask = np.array([False,True,False,True,False,True])
```

And there is additional Parameter called threshold=2

I want to subset M with mask only until 2 True values, for all of the remaining I would set false.
That means that M[mask] should return me second and fourth row only not the last one. Is there an efficient way to do this with numpy avoiding for loops?

Comment: Do you have a loop based working solution?

Comment: I mean yeah ist super easy, just while loop checking for True in the Array and than when threshold is 0 you set the rest of the mask to False.

Comment: Just chain boolean indexing using `mask` and then slice. Check the docs on indexing in numpy https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go along two ways:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [1,2,3],
              [1,2,3],
              [1,2,3],
              [1,2,3],
              [1,2,3]])

mask = np.array([False,True,False,True,False,True])

true_locs = np.where(mask)[0]

# set True to False in the mask
mask[true_locs[2:]] = False

# OR just use the indeces directly
M[true_locs[:2],:]
```

Answer (score 3):

`M[mask][:2]`

this selects your rows according to the mask and stops after reaching 2 `True` values.